# find element with dynamic name using jquery - Quotes problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I'm searching through my DOM based on the value an option in a select box has.

"searchkey" can be different things, depending on what a user has entered, e.g:

- searchkey = dell'anno
- searcheky = dell"anno

Those options (first one in this case) will break my code below because of the quote. Is there a native jQuery way to solve this?

```
.uiDialog.find("#var_variantnew_options option[value='"+searchkey+"']")).html()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery offers you several ways to do the same thing. Of course you can escape as Mathias suggested, it works. But sometimes it takes less time to just go a different route. Like using a filter function instead:

```
.UiDialog.find("#var_variantnew_options option").filter(function () {
  return this.value==searchkey;
}).html();
```

Comment: +1, was about to answer with a similar solution but you beat me to it. This is far more robust than escaping individual characters.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the filter function, didn't know about that yet.

Comment: Please use `this.value` instead of `$(this).attr('value')`. There’s no need to instantiate a new jQuery object.

Comment: @Mathias: Yeah, you're right. I always try to suggest initializing as few jQuery objects as possible, but sometimes I commit the same crime ;).

Answer (score 4):

You’ll need to escape the `'` characters, like this: `\'`

This can be automated as follows:

```
"foo'bar'baz".replace(/'/g, "\\'"); // "foo\'bar\'baz"
```

The full code snippet would be:

```
.uiDialog.find("#var_variantnew_options option[value='" + searchkey.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "']")).html()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm looking for a native jQuery way if that exists. It may as well be double quotes that need escaping. I know .text() does that in jQuery but I'm not sure if that can be used in this case

Comment: @Jorre: Since you’re need it in a selector I can assure you this is the easiest way.

Comment: @Mathias: Sorry, meant @Jorre

Comment: @Jorre: This is native Javascript. You cannot provide your string without escaping the characters that you determine are problematic. Use .replace and move on.

Comment: Escaping is risky. A lot of other characters could break the selector, including `]`, `=`, \.

Comment: Box9: Not if you escape all quotes, as I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/escape